# How would I represent the following prolog statement in predicate logic?

Tags: prolog, logic, predicate

How would you transform the following prolog statement to predicate logic?

```
hates(amy, X).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LaTeX's `\forall` to denote the universal quantifier, the meaning of `hates(amy,x).` is:

```
\forall x hates(amy,x)
```

In general, Prolog variables that occur in a program are universally quantified and Prolog variables that occur in a query are existentially quantified. For instance `?- hates(amy,x).` would be represented by `\exists x hates(amy,x)` in FOL.

Comment: +1 agreed. There is a distinction between the translation to FOL depending on whether the statement is a [fact, or a query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause#Logic_programming).