# No permission to modify static procedure `(\+)/1'

Tags: prolog

I have the followings:

```
mother(grimalde).
daughter(biancaneve, grimalde).
love(X, Y) :- mother(X), daughter(Y, X).
\+(kill(X, Y)) :- mother(X), daughter(Y, X), love(X, Y).
```

when I run `consult('ex.pl').` I get:

```
?- consult('ex.pl').
ERROR: /home/antonio/Scrivania/ex.pl:4:
    No permission to modify static procedure `(\+)/1'
    Defined at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/init.pl:242
% ex.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 0 clauses
```

And I don't understand why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog you cannot use negation in a clause head.

#### Definite clauses

Remember that Prolog clauses are *definite clauses*, i.e. conjunctions of literals of which exactly one is positive. This positive literal is called the *head* of the clause and is the part preceding the "`:-`".

Abstracting a bit, your clause looks like this:

```
\+H :- B1, B2, B3
```

which corresponds to the following clause:

```
\+H, \+B1, \+B2, \+B3
```

which is not definite.

#### Negation as failure

Also remember that Prolog negation is not logical negation but ***negation as failure***. In that sense `\+(kill(X,Y))` should be read "In this Prolog program it cannot be derived that `X` kills `Y`."

#### Permission error

So why do you get a permission error? Since `\+/1` is not interpreted negating the clause head (since the Prolog language does not allow this), it seems like you are *redefining* `\+/1`. Since `\+/1` is the outer functor of the clause head, it looks as if you are defining it. But redefining this predicate is not allowed.

Comment: one question, in prolog, every time i write a clause (i.e. p(x) :- a(x)) the $\forall$ is implicit?

Comment: @antox Indeed, in general unbound variables that occur in the program are universally quantified in Prolog. However, notice that unbound variables that occur in a Prolog query are existentially quantified. See [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840140/how-would-i-represent-the-following-prolog-statement-in-predicate-logic/25841289#25841289) for more details.